# Creating SQL Database in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I want to create a database in Visual Studio and then deploy it to a network drive. I've created the database, but I'm not sure how to deploy it without needing a server.

Comment: AFAIK you can't use a SQL Server database without mounting it in a running instance of SQL Server.

Comment: ***WHAT*** database? You can create a great many databases in Visual Studio - and `sql` is just the **query language** used by almost all relational database systems ....